# Download a file using URL in WPF Application without opening browser

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to download a file using the download link URL using C# WPF Application without opening the browser? 
For example: The link - http://example.url.com when typed into the address bar of the browser automatically downloads a file. How can i download this file upon a button click in WPF application (C#) without opening the browser?

TIA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you want to download a specific file and store it on your machine:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(remoteFilename, localFilename);
    ...
}
```

or [`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you want the page's content as a `string`:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
    ...
}
```